# What's the easiest way or method to automate the adding of a user to a fresh sudoers file?

Tags: linux, sed, root, sudoers

so, I've adduser'ed micronxd. I've passwd'd micronxd. now I wanna make micronxd a sudo user.

I'm trying to pack as much of this process into a shell script as possible. If possible, could the solution involve sed'ing the sudoers file? I'd like to get a really strong grasp on that beastly little nugget (sed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sudoers` file should really only be edited with `visudo(8)`.

That said, perhaps you should just add `micronxd` to the `wheel` group when adding the `micronxd` user, (see `adduser(8) --add_extra_groups` option) and then add this line to `sudoers` (via `visudo(8)` :) :

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now, every user you create with the primary group or a supplementary group of `wheel` gets `sudo` access automatically. You may never need to edit the `sudoers` file again.

(Note that you can easily add anyone you want to the `wheel` group; `vigr(8)`, find the `wheel` group, and append their login name to the line. Use commas to separate user names.)

Comment: Your way seems better than my stupid sed method lol
Thanks much!

Comment: MicronXD, there's nothing wrong with learning `sed`, I wish I knew it (and `awk`) better myself. :)

Comment: +1 Plus you can create other groups and assign the groups different combinations of rights. Then, like you said, it's a simple matter of adding a user to the `backup` group or the `reports` group.

Comment: is it always ALL=(ALL) ALL? (I mean for the syntax. I understand those "ALL"s can be something else). also, is there a PM feature on this site?

Comment: MicronXD, no PM feature (which they consider a feature -- this _isn't_ a social networking site -- but it does make some simple communication more difficult than it could be). The `sudoers(5)` file format is _very_ flexible; take a look at the `EXAMPLES` section in the `sudoers(5)` manpage for a very quick overview of awesome configuration options you can have. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK OK OK! I totally got it.
This may be a bit overkill, but I'm not sure if sudoers files are alike across diff distros.

> I found documentation on the holding buffer for sed here:
>   http://anaturb.net/sed.htm
>
> and on the x command for sed here:
>   http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/hands_off_editing_with_sed_part_2.htm

and I came up with this:
`sed -e '/^root/{h;}' -e 'x' -e 's/root/micronxd/' -e 'x' -e '/^root/G' -e 'wsudoers' sudoers`

Here's the breakdown of the 6 steps:

`1.` **'/^root/{h;}'**

finds uncommented lines starting with **root**, and replaces the holding buffer with it.

- regular sed buffer: [the whole sudoers file]
- holding buffer: **root     ALL=(ALL)     ALL**

`2.` **'x'**

swaps the holding buffer with the regular "to be sed'd" buffer.

- regular sed buffer: **root     ALL=(ALL)     ALL**
- holding buffer: [the whole sudoers file]

`3.` **'s/root/micronxd/'**

replaces root with micronxd

- regular sed buffer: **micronxd     ALL=(ALL)     ALL**
- holding buffer: [the whole sudoers file]

`4.` **'x'**

swaps the holding buffer with the regular "to be sed'd" buffer, again.

- regular sed buffer: [the whole sudoers file]
- holding buffer: **micronxd     ALL=(ALL)     ALL**

`5.` **'/^root/G'**

the G appends the holding buffer after the line matching **^root**.

- regular sed buffer (just the relevant bits):

> `##` Allow root   ALL=(ALL)   ALL to run any commands anywhere
>   root  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
>   micronxd  ALL=(ALL)   ALL

- holding buffer: **micronxd     ALL=(ALL)     ALL**

`6.` **'wsudoers'**

writes the regular sed buffer back to sudoers

I'm sure there's a better way, but I'm trying to get the hang of sed. plus, I wasn't sure if `user  MACHINE=COMMANDS    ????` is the syntax for all linux systems, or just fedora (which is what I'm dealing with).

Anyways, I'm happy to see other ways (especially better ways).